# ¿Cómo validar una URL que no permita agregar código javascript?

Tags: javascript, http, https

validar que en la barra url de mi pagina no permita escribir código javascript para que no se pueda obtener información de mi cookie, abajo se muestra la imagen del problema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

No se puede, todo usuario puede siempre que quiera ver las cookies que haya en su navegador. No tienes más que abrir la consola con <kbd>F12</kbd> y escribir `document.cookie`.